# NgIf performances issue applied on div rather than on an ng-container

Tags: angular

I'm coding an application that, at the current state, is not very big. It doesn't have any issue on performances but I noticed a strange behavior. I've three components:

```
map.component
dashboard.component
info.component
```

The `map.component` has a method that notify the `dashboard.component` using a `Subject` to change the state of a boolean variable (default value is setted to false):

```
// Dashboard component
private changeState(): void {
    this.showSomething = !this.showSomething;
}
```

This variable's state is reflected in the `dashboard.component.html` in this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showSomething">
    <div class="info-wrapper">
        <custom-component></custom-component>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

The `info-wrapper` class is just a flex display with `flex-grow: 1`.

I've putted a break point on the `constructor` in my `custom.component` and the application works like a charm. When `showSomething` change to true the render is nearly instantaneous.

But if I change the  `dashboard.component.html` this way:

```
<div class="info-wrapper" *ngIf="showSomething">
    <custom-component></custom-component>
</div>
```

`only the first time` that `showSomething` change to `true` the div `info-wrapper` takes nearly five second to be rendered. This means that if I change this variable to false and then to true again, the render of that component is nearly instantaneous.

I'm not using any animation or custom libraries (except for Toastr).

What could be the issue?

I'm also adding some relevant stuff.

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        NngMapComponent,
        NngMainComponent,
        NngInfoComponent,
        NngLoginComponent,
        NngWidgetComponent,
        NngLevelsComponent,
        NngFooterComponent,
        NngHeaderComponent,
        NngDashboardComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        routing,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
            preventDuplicates: true
        }),
        AngularResizedEventModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        EnvService,
        DataService,
        ShareService,
        TranslationService,
        AuthenticationService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [NngMainComponent]
})
```

`package.json dependencies`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "angular-resize-event": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be two cases where your component is not rendering or taking time to render.

**case 1 : If the changes were not detected**

This happens very rarely in which the angular is not able to detect the change in the value of **showSomething**. In this case you can programatically say angular to detect the changes in your component using change detector reference. You can refer from [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

**case 2 : There might be some task running** **in your custom component** (like Api call) after which you are displaying the component.

In this case you can display a loading screen instead of leaving the component blank. To know if your use case comes under this scenario write some log statements inside your `custom component constructor` and check the time taking to print logs

Comment: Thank you for response. The component is not doing any api call, just parsing some data before showing its content (there is a spinner while it's doing this). I guess I'll try out with the `OnPush` strategy.